# PHP Code Within Element Causes Repetition

Tags: php

I'm finding that placing php code snippets within my website's  &  tags is causing a problem with the code after it's placement. I first noticed it when placing avatars on my site in a list format where it works fine up to a point and then the same image is repeated for the rest of the list.  Here is the code that I'm uisng for that:

```
<?php

$show_user .= "

        <div class=\"section\">
            <div class=\"sectionInner\">
                <div class=\"searchAvatar\"><img class=\"searchAvatarSize\" src=\"uploads/avatars/$member_avatar\"></div>
                <div class=\"searchInformation\"><div class=\"searchInformationPrimary\">$member_name</div><div class=\"searchInformationSecondary\"><i>&quot;$member_summary&quot;</i></div></div>
                <div class=\"searchInformation\"><div class=\"searchInformationPrimary\">$member_subtype $member_type</div><div class=\"searchInformationSecondary\">$member_city, $member_county</div><div class=\"searchInformationThird\"><a href=\"event.php?id=$event_id&url=".urlencode($url)."\">View Details</a></div></div>
                <div class=\"clearLeft\"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"searchResultSplitter\"></div>

    ";
?>
<?php echo $show_user; ?>
```

I'm now noticing it when placing php within my navigation bar where it's not closing the  tag.  Here is my code for the bar:

```
<div id="pageSubNavigation" class="page<?php echo $thispage; ?>SubNavigation">
    <a href="page2.php" class="">Next Page</a>
</div>
```

After this, all of the other  tags show the same link. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Without seeing the whole page, I'll go off a couple assumptions based on what is linked.

1) Where are you storing $thispage?

Comment: Can you show some of the other links? Also, the first bit of code you provided, do you echo that? If so, can you provide the full code? It's hard to advise when you leave out code or syntax which could potentially be the issue.

Comment: Your php code gives a syntax error at the first `<`

Comment: @Telshin - $thispage is stored within the PHP of the page above the html

Answer (score 0):

You need to either jump out of the HTML to add the variables or wrap them in {} so they appear correctly.

Example:

```
<div class=\"searchAvatar\"><img class=\"searchAvatarSize\" src=\"uploads/avatars/".$member_avatar."\"></div>
```

or

```
<div class=\"searchAvatar\"><img class=\"searchAvatarSize\" src=\"uploads/avatars/{$member_avatar}\"></div>
```

Check out [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) about string formatting with variables in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the info but this has made no difference to the output!

Comment: Tested it with the example you provided http://pastebin.com/dfE2kadF

I'm thinking you have something amiss somewhere else in your code. The variables are not being passed to page or something.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a closer look at the rest of the code used on those pages

Comment: No problem. Without knowing more, I can not provide more insight. I hope it helps.